# Quick algorithm to compute the order mod m for an element from quadratic field?

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic, modules

For $a+b\sqrt{q}$,where a, b, q are integers and q is square-free, what's the quick algorithm to find the minimal integer n that $(a+b\sqrt{q})^n=1\pmod{m}$?

P.S. $(a_1+b_1\sqrt{q})(a_2+b_2\sqrt{q})=c+d\sqrt{q}\pmod{m}$, where $c=(a_1a_2+b_1b_2q)\pmod{m}$,$d=(a_1b_2+b_1a_2)\pmod{m}$

Comment: Define *quick*.

Comment: $O(m)$ or $O(ln(m))$ or even better. The naive way is to try each n one by one until we get one or proof that there is no such n. The worst case would be $O(m*m)$. Can we do better?

Comment: @notbad: The algorithm you just described is $O(m)$ operations, not $O(m^2)$. And if you multiply integers in the simplest way, each operation takes $O((\ln m)^2)$ time.

Comment: @Hurkyl There are $m^2$ elements in the set $\{a+b\sqrt{q}|a,b\in\{0,1,...,m-1\}\}$. In the worst case, you will traverse all the elements, it will take $O(m^2)$. The problem is how to avoid some integers, which can't be the right n?

Comment: @notbad: Oh, you're right, this is the quadratic extension.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure solving this problem gives you a way to factor $m$, so it's unlikely you can get the running time anywhere near $O((\ln m)^e)$, for any integer $e$.

I believe the state of the art is that you factor $m$, then determine the order of the multiplicative group of units in $Z/m(\sqrt{q})$. Then you just have to try the $n$ that divide the order of that group.

Comment: What's the effective way to determine the order of the multiplicative group?